# Library for react native application icon badge

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I'm looking for a library which can be used in react native to handle both `android` and `ios` application badge count. I'm currently using `react-native-onesignal` to handle push notifications. Onesignal does not support handling the application badge count on client side.

For `ios` I can programmatically set badge count. 
For android I can use react-native-badge-android library.

But I need a library for both `ios` and `android`?, 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

mybe you can try lib this https://github.com/7kfpun/FinanceReactNative this library for both ios and android

Comment: this library does not cover the demands on requestor. Please read more carefully